# looking for a way to adjust WPF Grid layout based on window width

Tags: wpf

I have an application that displays information on a window based on user control. You can click a button to add a user control in the next row and subscribe to a different skill to get that skills information. you can do this as many times as you want.

I'm looking for a way so when the window reaches a certain size in width all of the row cells become column cells and the column cells become row cells and instead of aligning like it currently is, it will adjust to the way the window is sized.

I'm not sure if what I'm asking already exists or not or if there is something other then a Grid that might do this.

ScreenShots to explain what I mean better:
[image]  This is how it is now[image] This is my drawing of how i would like it to auto convert to when the width gets small enough

Also adding the XAML of the usercontrol:

```
<Grid Loaded="DisplayNumber_Loaded" MaxWidth="540" MaxHeight="40">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>            
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="AgentWindow" Click="AgentWindow_Click">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="button" Text="agent"/>
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Open Full Agent List" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Open Aux Only" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
            </Button>
            </Grid>        

            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TeamNameText" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="Team Name"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SkillNum"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="Skill Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"/>
            </Grid>        

        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
            <Image Margin="5, 5, 5, 5" x:Name="CallImage" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>   

        <Grid Grid.Column="3">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="WaitTimeText" Text="Wait Time"/>

                <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15" x:Name="AgentAvailableData" Text="Available Number"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="12" x:Name="WaitTimeData" Text="Wait Time"/>            
        </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="4">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
            </Grid>        
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="HotSeat" Text="HotSeat" MouseDown="HotSeat_MouseDown" MouseLeave="HotSeat_MouseLeave"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code and explain with a little example what exactly you mean with the *"all of the row cells become column cells and the column cells become row cells [...]"* part?

Comment: Maybe you just need a `WrapPanel` or `UniformGrid`, but it's impossible to say with the level of detail information you currently provide

Comment: sorry for the wait. had a problem i had to deal with. I added some screen shots, also added the xaml of the user control that displays this currently

Comment: also just to add that when i add the WrapPanel to test it severely screws up the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, depending on your exact layout needs, there are several containers that are easier to handle than `Grid`. Here are two examples, featuring `WrapPanel` and `StackPanel`. Others could also work, if different detail layout is required.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:RestrictedWidthConverter x:Key="RestrictedWidthOverflowConverter" WidthLimit="300"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <!-- Take 1: just wrap with available space, no sudden re-layout -->
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Test1" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test2" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test3" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test4" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test5" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test6" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test7" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test8" Margin="20"/>
    </WrapPanel>
    <!-- Take 2: trigger orientation based on some parent element ActualWidth (could be the window) -->
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Test1" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test2" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test3" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test4" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test5" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test6" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test7" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Test8" Margin="20"/>
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grid1,Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource RestrictedWidthOverflowConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

With width to boolean converter

```
public class RestrictedWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double WidthLimit { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            var width = (double)value;
            return width <= WidthLimit;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In order to adjust the content layout (assuming this question is about a side toolbar panel), it might be a good idea to wrap the toolbar and the main content inside a `DockPanel` and to alternate the toolbars `DockPanel.Dock` property with the layout change:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Items ... -->
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grid1,Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource RestrictedWidthOverflowConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Left"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- The main content area element -->
    <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Green" Background="Gray"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: the comment for "the main content area element" should that not be inside of the stackpanel?

Comment: No, the stackpanel is only for stacking items in one direction. I imagine that you have some content that does not belong to your items collection, but you can ignore the last part of my answer if I misinterpret your usage scenario.